# Can the path of Nginx access_log take variable?

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-config

I want to put variable $host in the file path of Nginx access_log:

```
http {
   log_format compression '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
                       '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
                       '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" 
   "$gzip_ratio"';

 server {
     gzip on;
     access_log /var/logs/$host.access.log compression;
 }
}
```

Based on Nginx doc: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html, $host is embedded variable, and should work in the log path. However, it doesn't work in my case. Can anyone provide some hints here? My Nginx version is 1.10. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

maybe do not support  , that is test result

```
[root@l nginx.d]# nginx -s quit
[root@l nginx.d]# nginx 
[root@l nginx.d]# ls /var/log/nginx/
access.log  error.log  ${host}.log  $host.log  $server_name.log
[root@l nginx.d]# cat cms.0.dev.q.com.on 
server{

    server_name
        cms.0.dev.q.com 
        cms-0.dev.q.com 
        ;

    error_log /var/log/nginx/${host}.log warn;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/$server_name.log;
```

Answer (score 0):

Per the nginx docs, when using a variable in the name, buffered writes don't work, and gzip compression is a buffered write. So you can have a variable, or gzip on, but not both unfortunately.

Answer (score -1):

Try to set server_name parameter first. Also look at this working example:

```
server {
            if ($host ~* www\.(.*)) {
                    set $host_without_www $1;
                    rewrite ^(.*)$ http://$host_without_www$1/ permanent;
            }
            server_name_in_redirect off; #or folders like /awstats will redirect to _
            listen 80;
            server_name _;
            access_log      /var/log/nginx/$host.access_log main;
            error_log      /var/log/nginx/$host.access_log info;
            root /var/www/$host/htdocs;
            location ~ \.php$ {
                    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
                    fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:1026;
                    fastcgi_index index.php;
            }
    #For WP
            if (!-e $request_filename) {
                    rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.php?q=$1 last;
            }
    }
```